# What is the best way to sandbox collections in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I want to isolate each user's data from all other users.  What is the best way to keep a user viewing and modifying only her stuff?  My approach has been to

1. Add a userId field on *every* collection
2. Configure every published collection to filter on userId.
3. Use simple-schema with collections2 and add `autoValue: function(d) { return this.userId }` on the userId field for each schema to force the userId during validation.

Is this a good and correct approach?  What is best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dk. this sounds like a good approach to me and is considered best practice as well (as of my experience with meteor).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds solid. Actually I use this approach in a quite large project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I also use composite collections using the reywood:publish-composite package.

As a result some collections don't have userId keys but the documents for the current user are selected based on a document from a related collection. I'm also dealing with the case that many documents are shared between users.

This affords some degree of normalization while working really well.